# python 2.7.5+ split list ['a', 'xxx yyy zzz'] into list ['a', 'xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz'] how?

Tags: python, string, list, split

How do I split

```
list = ['a', 'xxx yyy zzz']
```

into

```
list = ['a', 'xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz']
```

in Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 19 2013, 13:48:49) [GCC 4.8.1] on linux2) ?

It tried with

```
...
for i in range(0, len(list)):
    list[i] = list[i].split(' ')
...
```

but with no results.

Comment: What exactly is the criterion for splitting? Splitting at whitespace? Splitting into parts of 3 characters or less? ...

Comment: Hi Lucas. It's splitting at the space between e.g. the string xxx and the string yyy. Thanks for your reaction ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> [word for s in L for word in s.split()]
['a', 'xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz']
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with list comprehension, like this

```
my_list = ['a', 'xxx yyy zzz']
print [word for words in my_list for word in words.split()]
```

**Output**

```
['a', 'xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz']
```

**Suggestion:** Never name your variable as `list` as it shadows the builtin [`list`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) function

Comment: Just named it "list" in the context of the question ;-) Don't worry I don't do it in real code. Thanks for your reaction.

Answer (score 3):

One quick and dirty way is:

```
l = ['a', 'xxx yyy zzz']
l = " ".join(l).split()
```

A better one is:

```
l = ['a', 'xxx yyy zzz']
l = sum((s.split() for s in l), [])
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution with [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and unbound method [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#str.split):

```
>>> lst = ['a', 'xxx yyy zzz']
>>> sum(map(str.split, lst), [])
['a', 'xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz']

>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(map(str.split, lst)))
['a', 'xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz']
```